# alignment/spacing inside a cell in a table when a vector is used

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|}
    \hline 
     & eigenvalues & Eigenvector\\\hline        
    $A_1* A_2$ & all the roots of \newline
    $x^3-x^2-(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h)x+abcdefgh=0$  & 
    $\left(\begin{array}{c}k_1x_i\\k_2y_i\\z_i\end{array}\right)$\\\hline   
   \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Observe in the last column and last row spacing. It seems odd. The array comes up aligned whereas the previous cell is bottom aligned. So how it could be rectified. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `m` column type provided by `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{booktabs} % for the second example

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\raggedright}m{3cm}|c|}
\hline 
& Eigenvalues & Eigenvector\\
\hline
$A_1 A_2$ &
  all the roots of 
  $x^3-x^2-(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+\nolinebreak h)x+abcdefgh=0$  & 
    $\begin{pmatrix} k_1x_i \\ k_2y_i \\ z_i \end{pmatrix}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{c>{\raggedright}m{3cm}c}
\toprule
& Eigenvalues & Eigenvector\\
\midrule
$A_1 A_2$ &
  all the roots of 
  $x^3-x^2-(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+\nolinebreak h)x+abcdefgh=0$  & 
    $\begin{pmatrix} k_1x_i \\ k_2y_i \\ z_i \end{pmatrix}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I added `\raggedright` for better typesetting in the narrow column. After seeing the result, it turned out to add also a `\nolinebreak` in order to avoid a bad line break.

The second table is built with `booktabs` features: its aspect is lighter and removal of the vertical rules helps in reading it.

[image]

Where's the problem with your table? The `p` column type makes each cell to have as reference point the baseline of the first line inside it. The third column has just one line and the baseline, just like for every other `array`, unless differently specified, is midway from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment (since much of the material is in math mode) and use `m` rather than `p` for the middle column. Since no linebreaks are needed in the final column, use the `c` column type for that column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{$}m{#1}<{$}} % math-mode version of "m" col. type
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
 \[
 \begin{array}{|c|M{3.35cm}|c|}
    \hline
     & \text{eigenvalues} & \text{eigenvector}\\
    \hline
    A_1*A_2 & \text{all roots of } 
    x^3-x^2-(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h)x+\mathit{abcdefgh}=0  &
    \begin{pmatrix}
    k_1x_i \\ k_2y_i \\ z_i
    \end{pmatrix}\\
    \hline
 \end{array}
 \]
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```